# Regex to find a username case insensitive

Tags: java, android, regex, parse-platform

I am trying to create a method to check for unique usernames. For example, if the username `JOHN` exists, someone else shouldn't pick the username `John`. My only problem is that I can't find the good regex for it. I tried the following:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
String regex = nickname.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
query.whereMatches("username", regex, "i");
```

But this also gives the users who have the username `Johnny`. How can I only find the username `John` case insensitive?

Comment: Can't you use `.equalsIgnoreCase`?

Comment: Nope, I am using Parse. https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not familiar with this API, but I guess it's more performant than `query.get(..)` or `query.getInBackground(..)` to get all the usernames and then doing a case-insensitive check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `"username"` with `"^username$"` should ensure that the entire string matches. Since you are passing the `i` flag, it should match without taking into consideration the difference in casing.

That being said, I am not 100% sure if regular expressions are the answer, since all you need to do is case insensitive comparisons, which should be handled by some string function.